# How to deploy react app with 2 different ports

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to serve a build on my network with 2 ports.

**1 for frontend which is localhost:3000 and 1 for server with localhost:3001**

I currently have the build for my frontend, but the problem here is i wanted to access the localhost:3001

[image: Image for Serving the build]

On localhost:3001 which is for development and not for deployment
. As you can see in the image, I can communicate with localhost:3001

[image: Development env]

But when i try the **BUILD FRONTEND WITH 192.168.254.100:300 ** It can't find my server (port 3001)

[image: Build trying to access port 3001]

**EDIT**

I'm successful on solving the first problem. But, another problem is i can't access the site on using a mobile phone without cors extension from chrome. And as well as the **COOKIES ARE NOT SETTING** in order to be authenticated.

[image: Cookies are not setting]

Answer (score 2):

This problems occurs due to the CORS policy. Basically, when you send a request from a URL that is different from your server URL, you'll be blocked. For example, if you communicate to your server using its own URL (localhost:3001), it works fine. However, if you do that from your frontend URL, CORS policy will block that. Therefore, in your server, you have to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your HTTP response. In Express, you can add the `cors` middleware.

First, go to your server folder and install `cors`:

```
npm i cors
```

In your entry point file of your server (`server.js`, `index.js`, or whatever), insert this line:

```
app.use(cors()); //This allow any websites to communicate to your server
```

If you want to only allow your frontend url to communicate and not others:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://192.164.254.100:3000" })
```

`app` is of course from:

```
const app = express()
```

Restart the server and it should works fine.

Comment: I'm successful on doing that, the last problem is the SESSION COOKIES are not able to set on the server.

Comment: What content do you want to store in the server's session and cookies? Session and cookies are mostly for the client. Hence, you may want to set those in client's browser using your frontend code

Comment: app.use(
  session({
    key: "userId",
    secret: "subscribe",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    proxy: "192.168.254.100:3001",

    //!remove this if cookie is needed.
    // cookie: {
    //   expires: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    // },
  })
);

This is my code on setting the session for the users.

Comment: Actually, I don't have much experience in session and cookies. I don't really know how other developers will implement this, but I will set the session and cookies in frontend code (javascript has built-in functions for this), and the information such as user id will be fetched from the server using axios or fetch API.